# Putting ngModel in input tag stops project displaying in browser

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel, ngmodel

I'm trying to use ngModel to get the text from a textbox, I have imported FormsModule in the way I believe I'm supposed to however anytime I put the [(ngModel)]="name" in the input tag it stops my project from displaying in the browser (project completely disappears)

I'm trying to follow a tutorial on getting the text from form controls to then use in an API call but so far I'm stuck on the first part of it :/
This is the tutorial I'm following: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ZkGUI6KNHY

Any help or ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Versions:
NPM: 6.9.0
Node: 10.16.3

manual-enter-details.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Output, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppComponent } from '../app.component';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule
  ]
})

@Component({
  selector: 'app-manual-enter-details',
  templateUrl: './manual-enter-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./manual-enter-details.component.css']
})
```

manual-enter-detials.component.html

```
<div id="Container">
        <br />
        <div id="InnerContainer">
<H3>Please enter your details</H3>

<label>Name: </label>
<input type="text" name="TxtBxName" [(ngModel)]="name" >


<br />
<br />
<label>Mobile: </label>
<input type="text" name="TxtBxMobile">
<br />
<br />
<br />
<div id = "button">
    <button type="button" class= "btn" (click)="ConfirmClick()" >
            Confirm
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

app.component.html

```
<style type="text/css">
  #Container {
      background-image: url('src\app\background.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  }
  </style>

<div id="Container">
  <app-begin *ngIf="ShowBegin" (BeginEmitter)="BeginClick($event)"></app-begin>
  <app-building-pass-tap *ngIf="ShowBuildingPassTap" (ForgotCardEmitter)="ForgotCardClick($event)"></app-building-pass-tap> 
  <BR />
  <app-identity-confirm *ngIf="ShowIdentityConfirm"></app-identity-confirm>
  <BR />
  <app-manual-enter-details *ngIf="ShowManualEnterDetails" (ConfirmEmitter)="ConfirmClick($event)"></app-manual-enter-details>
  <BR />
  <app-thank-you *ngIf="ShowThankYou"></app-thank-you>
  <BR />
  <app-cancel *ngIf="ShowCancel" (CancelEmitter)="CancelClick($event)"></app-cancel>
  <BR />
  <app-finished *ngIf="ShowFinished" (FinishEmitter)="FinishClick($event)"></app-finished>
</div>
```

Comment: If your HTML is not showing, there is likely an error. Could you post it please.

Comment: I've added the app.component.html code